# Groups generated by a subset

Tags: group-theory

Let $X,Y \subseteq G$.

1. Are $\langle X\rangle \cap \langle Y\rangle$ and $\langle X\cap Y\rangle $ equal?
2. Are $\langle \langle X\rangle \cup \langle Y\rangle\rangle$ and $\langle X \cup Y\rangle$ equal?

Remark: $\langle X\rangle$ here is the notation for intersection of all subgroups of G which contain X.

I am preparing for a midterm and trying to solve exercises at the end of each chapter. This is an exercise of Groups and Representations book by Alperin.

**My attempt**
I think that the intersection is not necessarily equal, however the union is equal. 
Then I need to find counter example for the intersection and prove that the unions are equal. However I do not know how to start.

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: Hint for the first one: Try to find a group $G$ and two generating sets $X$ and $Y$ of $G$, with $X\cap Y = \emptyset$. Take an easy group so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Hint for the second one: The answer is yes, and is basically an exercise in the definition of "subgroup generated by a set".

Comment: Could you maybe give a hint about group G? I was thinking about dihedral group, the group or reflections and rotations, but I couldn't find such generating sets. @Babelfish

Comment: @user1729 Could you please write a proof?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:

**Hint.** Note that $\mathbb{Z}=\langle 2, 3\rangle$.

For the second question, you basically need to understand that, for $S\subset G$, "$\langle S\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $S$". This means that if $x\in H$, for any $H\leq G$, then $\langle x\rangle\leq H$, right? With a bit of careful thought you can combine these facts to get that $\langle \langle X\rangle \cup \langle Y\rangle\rangle=\langle X \cup Y\rangle$.

[I am not convinced a full proof would be helpful for the second question. These things are better worked out by yourself, as it is really a definitions question. But possibly a nice, instructive example is that in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\langle 3, 6, 5, 10\rangle=\langle 3, 5\rangle$. Why?]

Comment: What is $H$ in your answer?

Comment: Also for the intersection I came up with simpler proof, $S_3$. $\{(12))\} \cap \{(13)\}$ is empty, however $<(12)> \cap <(13)>$ is identity, right?

Comment: And I would really appreciate if you could write down the proof in a proper way so that I can see how to construct proofs.

Comment: Your counter-example does not work, as in fact $\langle \emptyset\rangle$ is the trivial element (why?).

Comment: I have edited question. Please have a look to help with another direction

Comment: @MariyaKav Please don't edit a question after someone has answered it! People should not have to edit their answers to keep up with a changing question. Instead you should ask your edited question as a new question, and in it link back to this one.

Comment: (Incidentally, "linear algebra" is not an appropriate tag here. "abstract algebra", for example, is.)

Comment: In my new question someone said to make an edit.. I don't understand, instead of helping just discussing the edits

Comment: @MariyaKav I am not editing my answer to respond to the new question. If you want me (or someone else) to answer your new question you should do as I said above: ask your edited question as a new question, and in it link back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma (1):** If $A, B\subseteq G$ and $A\subseteq B$, then $\langle A\rangle \subseteq \langle B\rangle$. **Proof:** Let $a\in \langle A\rangle$. Then $a=a_1^{n_1}\cdots a_t^{n_t}$, where $a_i\in A$ and $n_i\in \Bbb{Z}$. Since $A\subseteq B$, we have $a_i\in B$. So $a\in \langle B\rangle$. Thus $\langle A\rangle\subseteq \langle B\rangle$.

**Lemma (2):** If $A\subseteq G$, then $\langle \langle A\rangle \rangle = \langle A\rangle $. **Proof:** Clearly $\langle A\rangle \subseteq \langle \langle A\rangle\rangle$. Let $a\in \langle \langle A\rangle\rangle$. Then $a=a_1^{n_1}\cdots a_t^{n_t}$, where $a_i\in \langle A\rangle$ and $n_i\in \Bbb{Z}$. Since $\langle A\rangle \leq G$, in particular $\langle A\rangle$ is closed under product in $G$, we have $a_i^{n_i}\in \langle A\rangle$ for all $i\in J_t$. So $a=a_1^{n_1}\cdots a_t^{n_t}\in \langle A\rangle$. Thus $\langle \langle A\rangle \rangle \subseteq \langle A\rangle$. Hence $\langle \langle A\rangle \rangle =\langle A\rangle$.

> **Claim:** $\langle \langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle \rangle = \langle X\cup Y \rangle$.

**Proof:** Since $X\subseteq \langle X \rangle$ and $Y\subseteq \langle Y \rangle$, we have $X\cup Y\subseteq \langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle$. By lemma (1), $\langle X\cup Y\rangle \subseteq \langle \langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle \rangle$. Since $X,Y\subseteq X\cup Y$, we have $\langle X \rangle , \langle Y \rangle\subseteq \langle X \cup Y\rangle$, by lemma (1). So $\langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle \subseteq \langle X\cup Y \rangle$. By lemma (2), $\langle \langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle \rangle \subseteq \langle \langle X\cup Y \rangle \rangle = \langle X\cup Y \rangle$. Thus $\langle \langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle \rangle = \langle X\cup Y \rangle$.

---

**Edit:** I just realised we don’t need lemma (2). We have $\langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle \subseteq \langle X\cup Y \rangle$. Since $\langle X\cup Y \rangle$ is a subgroup containing $\langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle$, we have $\langle \langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle \rangle \subseteq \langle X\cup Y \rangle$ because $\langle \langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle \rangle$ is “smallest” subgroup containing $\langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle$.