# What does it mean when a group is generated by a set of its subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

Let $G$ be a group, and $\{G_1, G_2, \dots, G_n\}$ be subgroups such that **"$G$ is generated by the subgroups $\{G_1, G_2, \dots, G_n\}$"**.

What does it mean for a group to be generated by a set of its subgroups?

Comment: It means that $G$ is generated by the union of the elements of those subgroups.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145442/subgroup-generated-by-a-set).

Comment: The only subgroup of $G$ containing $G_1, \dots, G_n$ is $G$ itself.