# Smallest of sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Can anyone show me how to solve this question extracted from Michael Taylor's book:

If $\{\mathcal{F}_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\}$ is the collection of all $\sigma$-algebras of subsets of $X$ that contain $\mathcal{C}$, show that $$\bigcap_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{F}_{\alpha} = \mathcal{F}$$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, containing $\mathcal{C}$, and is in fact the smallest such $\sigma$-algebra. One says $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$ and writes $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(\mathcal{C})$

Comment: You just have to verify the defining properties of a $\sigma$ algebra for the intersection and that $\cal{C}$ is contained in that intersection. Chase through the definitions. Since each member of the intersection has the corresponding properties this is actually straightforward.

Comment: Note that $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{F}_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A$. This proves minimality.

Comment: As I spell out below, it is not only for sigma-algebras that you use the technique that gets you the answer to this question; it's for many other things as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recall the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra: it is a collection of subsets of some particular $X$, such that:

1. It is closed under countable unions;
2. It is closed under taking complement (relative to $X$).

From this, countable intersections follow by DeMorgan's Laws.

Now suppose that $X_i\in\mathcal F$ for $i\in\mathbb N$. So for all $\alpha\in A$ we have $X_i\in\mathcal F_\alpha$. Since $\mathcal F_\alpha$ is a $\sigma$-algebra we have that $\bigcap X_i\in\mathcal F_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A$ and therefore $\bigcap X_i\in\bigcap\mathcal F_\alpha=\mathcal F$.

For complements, the principle is the same.

Furthermore, the same idea works to show that $\mathcal F$ contains $\mathcal C$. Lastly we need to show that this is indeed the smallest:

Suppose that $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\mathcal C$, then for some $\alpha\in A$ we have $\mathcal S=\mathcal F_\alpha$, so it took part in the intersection which generated $\mathcal F$, therefore $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal S$.

---

**Further Reading:**

1. [The $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ generated by a set $\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest sigma algebra including $\mathcal{A}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

If an XXXXX is defined as a set closed under certain operations, then any intersection of XXXXXs is another XXXXX.  The proof is as follows.  Suppose $\{A_\alpha : \alpha\in I\}$ is a set of XXXXXs and $u,v\in \bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$.  Then for every $\alpha\in I$, $u,v\in A_\alpha$.  Performing the operations on $u,v$ under which every XXXXX is closed, we conclude that what we get is in $A_\alpha$.  Since that's true of *every* value of $\alpha$, what we get is in $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$.  Therefore $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$ is an XXXXX.

**DO NOT** take "$u,v$" to mean just *two* things; construe it if necessary as a countably infinite or even bigger class of things, if the operations under which every XXXXX is closed require that.

Now instead of "an XXXXX", just say "an XXXXX of which $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset", and apply that argument.

That's the answer to your first question.  But if it's homework, it should be spelled out in more detail than what appears above.

Now what about "smallest"?  Now we need the assumption that $\{A_\alpha : \alpha\in I\}$ is not just a collection of XXXXs containing $\mathcal{C}$ as a subset, but is the collection of *all* XXXXXs containing $\mathcal{C}$ as a subset.

It's the smallest simply because for every $\alpha_0$, $\displaystyle A_{\alpha_0}\supseteq \bigcap_{\alpha\in I}A_\alpha$.  "Smallest" means simply that it's a subset of all others.

Comment: What???${}{}{}$

Comment: @Norbert: This way he gets the first answer. This is the equivalent of "FIRST!!" comments in other sites.

Comment: I do not like the XXXXX notation. I get lost when I try to count the Xs. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, I see...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Cannot be true, he did not. You were faster.

Comment: There's not "autosave" here, as far as I know.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, there is. For one answer when writing it originally, not when editing it. I would also recommend working in an external editor if you find your browser crashing often and not saving your work. Posting half-completed answers reflects poorly (as I wrote my impressed of the action - true or not - in my first comment).

Comment: @Thomas: Check again, he was about one minute "faster" than me.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You can delete your question, edit it and then undelete.

Comment: @AsafKaragila well, yes, but you got the credits.

Comment: @Thomas: Suppose I get +10 and accepted answer, I will not get Enlightened badge because it is not the first answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess you just have to wait a bit longer for the badge. And you already got +20 :-)

Comment: @Norbert : I'm guessing you meant "answer" rather than "question".

Comment: I don't think I would get anything for being "first".  My contribution that is not in the other answer is mainly that it is not _only_ in the case if sigma-algebras that this argument works; it's lots and lots of things.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, of course I meant answer

Comment: @MichaelHardy there is one X missing. In the third last paragraph you wrote XXXX instead of XXXXX once. I saw this coming, the notation is no good.

Comment: @Thomas : Your contribution is of course greatly appreciated, but you missed a much more substantial typo: I had "subseteq" where of course I needed "supseteq".

Comment: @MichaelHardy I do appreciate confessions like this, but I'd even more appreciate a correction of the typo (and of course the one you were just pointing out yourself). Even more I's appreciate a replacement of XXXXX by something less unpleasant.

Comment: How about some ZZZZZ instead?