# About Borel bounded functions

Tags: measure-theory

I am studying the book of Reed and Simon, Functional Analysis and I am not able to prove the following exercise (16 on chapter 1):

Prove that the bounded Borel functions on $[0,1]$ are the smallest family $\mathcal{F}$ which includes $C[0,1]$ and has the property: If $f_n$ is a sequence of uniformly bounded function in $\mathcal{F}$ and $f_n\to f$ pointwise, then $f\in \mathcal{F}$.

I appreciate the tips and/or solutions.

Comment: Do you know any version of the monotone class theorem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you know the construction of Borel sets by transfinite induction, this shouldn't be too hard to mimic: show that every bounded Borel function can be obtained by iterating a transfinite construction of adding pointwise limits of uniformly bounded sequences.

Comment: Borel sets: smallest family of subsets with the properties: closer under complements, closer under countable unions and contains each open intervals.

Comment: Perhaps this thread will interest you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s/