# Existence of minimal $\sigma$-algebra and transfinite induction

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

It is well-known that:

> Given a set $X$ and a collection $\cal S$ of subsets of $X$, there exists a $\sigma$-algebra $\cal B$ containing $\cal S$, such that $\cal B$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra satisfying this condition.

Certain texts, Lieb and Loss, *Analysis*, for instance, state that the proof of this assertion requires transfinite induction. On the other hand, one can define $\mathcal B$ to be the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\cal S$. Which statement is correct? Or, is there a hidden transfinite induction contained somewhere?

I must confess here that I have only vague ideaos of the rigorous set-theoretic foundations of mathematics.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s/ may be a thread of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras that include $\mathcal S$ is a perfectly good way to get the smallest such $\sigma$-algebra, and the proof that it works requires no transfinite induction.

Answer (score 2):

Lieb and Loss say no such thing, as far as I can tell.  In fact on page 4, it reads

> "Consider all the sigma-algebras that contain $\mathcal{F}$ and take their intersection, which we call $\sum$, i.e., a subset $A \subset \Omega$ is in $\sum$ if and only if $A$ is in every sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal{F}$.  It is easy to check that $\sum$ is indeed a sigma-algebra.  Indeed it is the smallest sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal{F}$..."

Comment: It goes through transfinite induction somewhere shortly afterwards.. It's unfortunate, I don't have a physical copy with me and I can't get an e-copy.

Comment: @DoubtingThomas It mentions transfinite induction in the context of passing an algebra to a $\sigma$-algebra. This is irrelevant to the existence of a minimal $\sigma$-algebra  (Given an algebra $\mathcal{A}$, taking countable unions yields a collection $\mathcal{A_1}$, which is not closed under countable intersections.  So taking countable intersections of $\mathcal{A_1}$ yields $A_2$..and so on.  Proceeding like this you get a the minimal $\sigma$-algebra of $A$).

Comment: So, why does not the same intersection argument work in the case of passing from algebra to $\sigma$-algebra ? After all, $\cal A$ is just another set and there exists a minimal $\sigma$-algebra containing it. If that proof is transfinite-induction free, it should work here too; no?

Comment: @DoubtingThomas It does work.  The book was talking more about the process of building a minimal $\sigma$-algebra of an algebra.  The existence part is clear, because you can just intersect all the $\sigma$-algebras containing $S$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot! The confusion is cleared.