# Modifying definition of $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let's start with basic definitions.

> Def. Given a set $X$  we say that $\Sigma\subset 2^X$ is **a $\sigma$-algebra**, if $X\in\Sigma,$ $\Sigma$ is closed under complementation and countable unions.
>
> Def. Given a family $\mathcal A$ of subsets of $X,$  we say that $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is **the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$**, if it is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A.$

Asaf Karagila said in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s/), that $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ has descriptive, but transfinite form. It is

- $\Sigma^0_0=\Pi^0_0=$ finite intersections from $\mathcal{A}$
- For countable ordinals $\alpha$ let:

$$\Sigma^0_\alpha=\{\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i\mid A_i\in\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\Pi^0_\beta\},\quad 
\Pi^0_\alpha = \{X\setminus A\mid A\in\Sigma^0_\alpha\},\quad 
\Delta^0_\alpha=\Sigma^0_\alpha\cap\Pi^0_\alpha$$
and then we define $\Delta=\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1} \Delta^0_\alpha.$

I heard of slightly different approach (I colored differences in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$), i.e.

- $\color{green}{\Delta_0=\mathcal{A}\cup\{\emptyset\}}$
- For countable ordinals $\alpha$ let:

$$\Sigma_\alpha=\{\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i\mid A_i\in\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\color{green}{\Delta}_\beta\},\quad 
\Pi_\alpha = \{X\setminus A\mid A\in\Sigma_\alpha\},\quad 
\Delta_\alpha=\Sigma_\alpha\color{green}{\cup}\Pi_\alpha$$

and then we define $\Delta=\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1} \Delta_\alpha.$

In both cases the claim is that $\Delta=\sigma(\mathcal A).$

I have no clue how someone is able to proof that, particularly the inclusion $\Delta\subset\sigma(\mathcal A),$ but I believe it can be done and I am willing to assume that $\Delta=\sigma(\mathcal A)$ in both cases above.

From now on, if I say transfinte induction, I mean the second one, i.e. the one with $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ elements.

I would like to create a new object $\Gamma,$ which I get from transfinite induction, but restricted to the finite ordinals, i.e. I just simply do normal induction and define $\Gamma=\bigcup_{n<\infty}\Delta_n.$ To be even more explicite, let's actually define it using good old normal induction. So we set

- $\Delta_0=\mathcal{A}\cup\{\emptyset\}$
- For every $n\in\mathbb{N}:$

$$\Sigma_n=\{\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i\mid A_i\in\bigcup_{k<n}\Delta_k\},\quad \Pi_n = \{X\setminus A\mid A\in\Sigma_n\},\quad \Delta_n=\Sigma_n\cup\Pi_n$$
and then we define $\Gamma=\bigcup_{n<\infty}\Delta_n.$

For me $\Gamma$ is big enought. But since $\Delta=\sigma(\mathcal A)$ and $\Gamma$ looks smaller than $\Delta$ it is likely that $\Gamma\neq\sigma(\mathcal A).$

Unfortunetely $\Gamma$ seems not to be even a $\sigma$-algebra, for the same reason that $\Delta$ is in fact $\sigma$-algebra. (See Arturo Magidin's answer) It fails to be closed under countable unions. But it fails, due to considering diagonal-like elements (and actually this is the reason why I define $\Gamma$ in such way).

**What is the idea! (don't be scared in first reading)**

I would like to define two new objects called $\gamma$-algebra and $\gamma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A.$ $\gamma$-algebra is defined similar to $\sigma$-algebra, but with $\color{blue}{\text{different (weaker) conditions}}$. $\gamma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$ is smallest such $\gamma$-algebra and it has descriptive form, which equals $\Gamma.$

In other words, I would like to end up with the following situation:

> Def. Given a set $X$  we say that $\Omega\subset 2^X$ is **a $\gamma$-algebra**, if $X\in\Omega,$ $\Omega$ is closed under complementation and $\color{blue}{\text{some conditions I ask you to invent}}$.
>
> Def. Given a family $\mathcal A$ of subsets of $X,$  we say that $\gamma$-algebra $\gamma(\mathcal A)$ is **the $\gamma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$**, if it is the smallest $\gamma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A.$
>
> Thm. Let $\mathcal A$ be a family of subsets of $X.$ If we define $\Gamma$ as above, then
>   $$\Gamma=\gamma(\mathcal A).$$

**The question**

What conditions should be in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such blue conditions exist.  Write $\Gamma(\mathcal{A})$ for your construction $\Gamma$ applied to a starting set $\mathcal{A}$. If there was such a notion of $\gamma$-algebra, then the operation $\gamma$ would satisfy $\gamma(\gamma(\mathcal{A}))=\gamma(\mathcal{A})$ (since $\gamma(\mathcal{A})$ is a $\gamma$-algebra, and hence is the smallest $\gamma$-algebra containing $\gamma(\mathcal{A})$).  Also your theorem would say that $\gamma(\mathcal{A})=\Gamma(\mathcal{A})$ for all $\mathcal{A}$, and so we must have $\Gamma(\Gamma(\mathcal{A}))=\Gamma(\mathcal{A})$ for all $\mathcal{A}$.   But this is not true, since  $\Gamma(\mathcal{A})$ is typically not closed under countable unions, whereas $\Gamma(\Gamma(\mathcal{A}))$ contains all countable unions of elements of $\Gamma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: I do not see why $\gamma(\gamma(A))$ contains all countable unions of elements of $\gamma(A).$ If we demand the condition that $\gamma$-algebra is closed under countable unions, then that would be the case. But the point of my question is to invent some alternative to closeness of countable unions.

Comment: I see now. I wrote stronger, but I ment weaker condition. My bad. I am going to change it.

Comment: By $\gamma(\mathcal{A})$ I meant your $\Gamma$ construction applied to $\mathcal{A}$; I've edited the answer to be clearer.

Comment: You are just right. But how could you be so sure with the statement: "No such blue conditions exist"? Is there any reason that none can come up with some bright idea and state contidion in blue in simple way?

Comment: My answer is a proof by contradiction that no such blue conditions exist.

Comment: @FallenApart  The Eric's argument is correct. Let me put in other words. If there is a concept of $\gamma$-algebra and we define $\gamma(\mathcal{A})$ to be the smallest $\gamma$-algebra  containing $\mathcal{A}$, then, as direct consequence of the definition, we have  $\gamma(\gamma(\mathcal{A}))= \gamma(\mathcal{A})$. However, $\Gamma(\Gamma(\mathcal{A}))\neq \Gamma(\mathcal{A})$. So, it is not possible that FOR ALL $\mathcal{A}$, $\Gamma(\mathcal{A})=\gamma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: Yep, I get it now. BTW this argument is so brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I have something. So the condition is following:

$\Omega$ admits a countable filtration $\Omega=\bigcup_{n<\infty}\Delta_n$ closed under countable bounded (with respect to filtration) unions, i.e. for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and every $A_1,A_2,\dots\in\Delta_n$ (these are bounded elements)
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\Omega$$
Condition $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\Delta_{n+1}$ would work as well, but the upper one is weaker.

The key idea is to forbid taking diagonal-like elements in countable unions. Boudedness do the job.

**Edit**

Eric is correct. In such definition, $\Gamma$ wouldn't be the smallest $\gamma$-algebra containing $\mathcal A.$

Comment: With this definition, it is not always true that $\Gamma$ is the smallest $\gamma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$; see my answer.