# Determine $\langle\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{I}} B_{\alpha}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am having problems with the next assigned homework:

Let $\{B_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in \mathbb{I}}$ a family of abelian subgroups. 
Determine $\langle\bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{I}} B_{\alpha}\rangle$

I think I can proove that:
$$  \left\langle\bigcup_{\alpha = 1}^{n} B_{\alpha}\right\rangle  = \sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}(B_i)$$

where $ B_1+ B_2 + ... + B_n = \{c = \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i:b_i \in B_i\}$

That is the case when $\mathbb{I} = \{1,2,...n\}$. But in general I do not know what is. I would try to $$\sum_{\alpha\in \mathbb{I}}B_i $$ but how we can determine c? in the case when $\mathbb{I} = \mathbb{N}$ for example.  I supposed that for a group the sum is closed but only when is finite. So, any idea?

Comment: This is known as the [join](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Join_of_subgroups) of the subgroups.

Comment: I take it your group is abelian? Otherwise the use of additive notation would be discourage; and if it is the case, you should mention it *somewhere*.

Comment: What is your definition of “subgroup generated by”? And have you established both the top-down and the bottom-up description?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin my definition is stated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175448/let-s-subseteq-a-a-is-a-group-then-langle-s-rangle-is-the-smallest-su?noredirect=1#comment6537729_3175448

Comment: The top-down definition. And have you proven the equivalence to the bottom-up description?

Comment: No, I just did the characterization that is the smallest element that contains the set.

Answer (score 1):

A generally useful strategy for proving two sets $S$ and $T$ are equal is to prove two implications: if $s\in S$ then $s\in T$, and if $t\in T$ then $t\in S$. This lets you work with specific objects $s$ and $t$, which (by virtue of the hypotheses) have certain forms that you can manipulate.

In this particular case, remember also that elements of spans and sums are, by definition, always *finite* sums of other elements, even if those other elements can potentially be drawn from infinitely many sets.

Comment: So, in that case I think I have the proof because it will be similar to $  \left\langle\bigcup_{\alpha = 1}^{n} B_{\alpha}\right\rangle  = \sum_{\alpha=1}^{n}(B_i)$