# Sheldon Axler Linear Algebra Done Right: Confused about "smallest containing subspaces."

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I have a few questions regarding Axler's proofs that concern "smallest containing subspaces": in particular, 1.39.

I understand we want to show that $U_1 + \cdots + U_m$ = the smallest subspace of V containing $U_1, \cdots, U_m$ by showing that each set is a subset of the other set. What I don't understand, however, is why Axler says "Conversely, every subspace of V containing $U_1 \cdots U_m$ contains $U_1 + \cdots + U_m$)" because isn't the point to compare $U_1 + \cdots + U_m$ with the SMALLEST subspace, not an arbitrary subspace?

[image]

Comment: To show it is the smallest, you want to show that (i) it is **a** subspace containing all of $U_1,\ldots,U_n$; and (ii) it is contained in *every* subspace that contains all of $U_1,\ldots,U_n$.

For general comments about this sort of thing, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s/54334#54334).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is a subspace containing $U_1,\ldots,U_m$, then $V\supset U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_m$. In particular, the smallest subspace containing $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ will also contain $U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_m$. But $U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_m$ is a subspace itself, which contains $U_1,\ldots,U_m$. So, $U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_m$ contains the smallest subspace containing $U_1,\ldots,U_m$, and therefore they're equal.

Comment: thank you very much!