# sigma algebra generated by class of supersets of a given set

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

**Question Source:** Extension of Example 1b in Section 6 from "Measure Theory" by Halmos

> For a fixed subset $A\subset X$, $E$ is the class of all sets of which $A$ is a subset, i.e. $E=\{F:A\subset F\}$. What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the class $E$ of sets here described?

**My Question**: I was wondering if there's a neat characterization or what Halmos intended for us to do/see here.

Comment: Neither of the "extremes" makes sense. Your $\{\Omega,\varnothing\}$ does not contain $E$ as a subset, so it cannot possibly be the "$\sigma$-algebra generated by $E$." The collection $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is too large, and it makes no sense to simply declare to be "the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $E$".  Do you understand what "the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a collection $E$"  is?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer will help clarify what is going on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54172/the-sigma-algebra-of-subsets-of-x-generated-by-a-set-mathcala-is-the-s/54334#54334), without telling you what the answer is.

Comment: I meant $\{X,\emptyset\}$ which would be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $E=\{X\}$. For the latter, I was just wrong.

Comment: Note that "$A\in X$" should be $A\subset X$. It's a subset, not an element.

Comment: Actually, for the second case, I am still not sure why it doesn't make sense. If $A=\emptyset$, then isn't $E=\mathcal{P}(X)$ and so the intersection of all such algebras containing the power set is the power set itself?

Comment: It was a bit discombobulated; perhaps my comment was not accurate, as I took it to mean "the extremes of what the $\sigma$-algebra generated could be."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal G$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $E$. It should necessarily contains the complements of the sets of $E$, that is, the sets contained in $X\setminus A$. If $S\subset X\setminus A$, then $S\in\mathcal G$ and $S\cup A\in\mathcal G$. Therefore, we can try
$$
\mathcal G=\left\{S\subset X, S\subset X\setminus A\right\}\cup \left\{A\cup S, S\subset X\setminus A\right\}
$$
and check that such a $\mathcal G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $E$, and it is the smallest for the inclusion doing this job.