# $a$ and $b$ are elements of the group $G$, then if $a \in \langle b \rangle$, then $\langle a\rangle \subseteq \langle b\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Assume that $a$ and $b$ are elements of the group $G$, then if $a \in \langle b\rangle $, then $\langle a\rangle  \subseteq \langle b\rangle$

How can I prove the foregoing identity? It is from the book modern algebra exercise $27$. It doesn't have solution in the book. Can you help me?

The only thing came to my mind:

$a$ is element of the set generated by $b$. If we say that the order of $\langle b\rangle$ is $k$, then $a^{xy}=b^k=e$. This knowledge doesn't help me

**Any link,answer or additional material appreciated !**

Comment: You cannot generally say *the order of $b$ is $k$*, because $k$ may be infinite!

Comment: Forget about order. Write down the definitions: What are you given and what must you prove?

Comment: @TedShifrin I want to prove the title

Comment: @TedShifrin which definitions ? this is just an exercise in the book

Comment: @randoman Ted Shifrin means: what is the definition of $\langle x\rangle$? The reason for this question is that (a) there are multiple (equivalent) ways to define this notation, so it's helpful to know which you're working with, and (b) like many exercises at the beginning of group theory, this is an example of an exercise which is very easy once you have written out the definitions.

Comment: $a=b^k$ for some $k$. Let $z\in\mathbb Z$, then $a^z=(b^k)^z=b^{kz}$.

Comment: **Duplicate** of many prior questions - should not have been answered (or asked).

Comment: @BillDubuque look at your own bussiness, not prevent my education

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a group $(G,\cdot)$ Let's have a look at the definitions
$$\langle b \rangle := \{g \in G : g = b^k, k\in \Bbb Z\}\\
\langle a \rangle := \{g \in G : g = a^h, h\in \Bbb Z\}$$

So we have that if $g \in \langle a \rangle $
$$g = a^h$$
For the hypothesis $a\in \langle b\rangle$ so we have
$$g = a^h = (b^k)^h = b^{kh}\in \langle b \rangle$$
This argument holds for every $g \in \langle a \rangle$ and so $\langle a \rangle \subseteq \langle b \rangle$.

---

P.S. I'm using multiplicative group notation could you prove the same holds in additive notation?

Comment: why did we say that $a^h=b^k=g$,, they do not have to generate all elements in G

Comment: if $g=a^h=b^k$, then why $a^h = b^{kh}$. This example burned me

Comment: You can prove the laws of exponents in any group using mathematical induction, more-or-less as you would prove them in the group $\mathbb R- \{0\}$ (except not the law $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ which requires the group to be abelian).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang ups... edited.

Comment: @randoman $g$ is used to indicate a general element in the group $G$, in the definitions $g$ is not the same element, it's just a notation. Do you need further elaboration?

Comment: Do you have *any* idea how many books are called "Modern Algebra"? If you are trying to identify a book, you need to provide both title and author.

Answer (score 4):

You really want to take this at a much more abstract level.

If $S$ is a subset of a group $G$, then $\langle S\rangle$ has the following **universal property**:

1. $\langle S\rangle$ is a subgroup; and
2. $S\subseteq \langle S\rangle$; and
3. If $H$ is **any** subgroup of $G$ such that $S\subseteq H$, then $\langle S\rangle\subseteq H$.

In fact, $\langle S \rangle$ can be *defined* as the unique subgroup of $G$ having these three properties (this is the "top-down definition"; you'll also want the "bottoms-up definition" of $\langle S\rangle$, which describes what the elements look like: products of powers of elements of $S$; see [here for a general discussion of these types of constructions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54334/742)).

Given that, if $a\in \langle b\rangle$, then since $\langle b\rangle$ is a subgroup, and $a\in \langle b\rangle$, it follows by property 3 above that $\langle a\rangle\subseteq \langle b\rangle$. Presto, done.

Comment: More like a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator).

Comment: @lhf as is discussed in the other post.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\langle x\rangle$ is all powers of $x$. If $a$ is a power of $b$, then all powers of $a$ are powers of $b$.